# How to make link open in the same tab

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a button in menu section with link to pop-up. 
I want to make so that it was opened in the same tab.

Here is the code of this button:

```
<button
class="btn btn-bg-no btn-border-green btn-color-green hvr hvr-buzz-out"
onclick="window.open('<?php echo esc_url( $menu_btn_url ); ?>', '_blank')">
    <?php echo esc_html( $menu_btn ); ?>
</button>
```

I was trying to change `'_blank'` to `'_self'`. It changes the url, but my pop-up didn't appear. What can I do?

Comment: Try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2906582/how-to-create-an-html-button-that-acts-like-a-link

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create an HTML button that acts like a link?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2906582/how-to-create-an-html-button-that-acts-like-a-link)

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the docs for <kbd>[window.open()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open)</kbd> you'll see the second parameter is actually for naming the window if it doesn't reference an existing context, and webkit (chrome) has been having issues for the longest time with this.

You mention the button triggers a pop-up, but `_self` would basically treat it like you're clicking on a standard link, no? You may be better off using a standard link:

```
<a class="btn btn-bg-no btn-border-green btn-color-green hvr hvr-buzz-out" href="<?php echo esc_url( $menu_btn_url ); ?>">
    <?php echo esc_html( $menu_btn ); ?>
</a>
```

If for some reason you want an `onclick` event, you'd probably be better suited using `window.location.href` instead of `window.open`:

```
<button class="btn btn-bg-no btn-border-green btn-color-green hvr hvr-buzz-out" onclick="window.location.href = '<?php echo esc_url( $menu_btn_url ); ?>'">
    <?php echo esc_html( $menu_btn ); ?>
</button>
```

---

> Also, a side note your SSL certificate on your website isn't working as it's issued to `auditerra.ru` and not `intererka.auditerra.ru` or `*.auditerra.ru`

Comment: And thank's a lot for your answer. Somehow it still opens it in a new tab.

Comment: It looks like the button still shows `window.open('#ulp-GNwyBk9RXdBMTICM','_blank')` on your site

Comment: Arghhh, yes, my fault. I tried now again and the link changes, but the popup don''t appear.

Comment: Ha, I was just about to say - now that I get exactly what you're trying to do, the standard `<a>` tag would be a better way to go about it - glad to help!